# Solvable group of order $pqr^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> $|G|=pqr^2$ where $3\leq p<q<r$ prime.  Show that if $r>\frac{1}{2}(pq-1)$ then $G$ is solvable.

I took $H\leq G$ $r$-sylow subgroup of $G$, there is a theorem claiming that there exists a homomorphism from $G$ to $S_{pq}$ ($pq$ is the index of $H$).

If the homomorphism is injective then $G$ is a subgroup of $S_{pq}$, that means $pqr^2|(pq)!$ so $r^2|(pq-1)!$ but we know $r^2>2r>pq-1$ from what follows that the homomorphism can't be injective, that means there is a non trivial kernel which is a maximal subgroup of $H$ and a normal subgroup of $G$, it can be of order $r$ or $r^2$, lets name it K.

If $|K|=r^2$ then the sequence $\{e\}\triangleleft K\triangleleft G$ has a factor of order $r^2$ which is abelian as a square of a prime and a factor of order $pq$.

The other option is $|K|=r$, then the factors are of order: $r$ and $pqr$.

I am a bit stuck from here.

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but if |G| = pqrr with 2 ≤ p < q < r, then G is solvable.  Squaring the largest prime factor doesn't help to get nonsolvable groups.  You need to square the smaller ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Groups of order $r$ are solvable.  Groups of order $pqr$ are solvable.  So your group is an extension of two solvable groups, so solvable.   In a group of order $pqr$, the Sylow $r$-subgroup is normal, and in the quotient of order $pq$, the Sylow $q$-subgroup is normal.

Comment: did you mention a group of order $pqr$ is solvable, once they are all prime and regardless of duplicity? May I ask how to get that?

Answer (score 2):

You are left to show that a group of order $pqr$ is solvable, and this can be done exactly the same way you began the $pqr^2$ case.

Comment: When p=3, q=5, r=11, Sym(pq) does not have order prime to r.  The order just is not divisible by r*r.

Comment: oops, sorry I thought we had $r>pq$

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases to consider: either the Sylow $r$-group is maximal, or it is normal in $G$.  Both cases lead to a solvable group. No conditions on $r$, further than $p < q< r$, are necessary.